# Workflowy + iCal integration

Tags: integration, icalendar

Tasks entered in Workflowy that have a date set, shall appear in my iCal.

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Frequently Asked Questions of WorkFlowy list, date is in plan.
iCal may be implemented by some guy using API...

> **What features are coming up for WorkFlowy?**
>
> The following are some of the features we plan on building into WorkFlowy. We'll implement them with the standard WorkFlowy style and simplicity.
>
> - Offline access
> - Dates & reminders
> - Multi-item selection
> - Colors and formatting
> - Collaboration improvements
> - API

Comment: Any updates on that so far? ("offline" and "API" items are very interesting at least)

Answer (score 1):

I agree that would be awsome, but as you might have guessed by now, nope not possible.. yet.